# Set non-continuous PrintArea via Function / Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to set a dynamic non-continuous print area via Function, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

I have a defined name for the print area: Print_Area.

To this Name I am able to pass a range eg `Sheet1!$E$2:$I$23` and I can dynamically switch to another range using the INDIRECT function based on the values of other cells. For example, as another defined Name: DynPrint

I set:

`=IF(Sheet1!$A$3="x",INDIRECT("Sheet1!$E$1:$I$22"),IF(Sheet1!$B$3="x",INDIRECT("Sheet1!$M$1:$Q$22"),INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$30")))`

This switches the print range if A3 is equal to x, or if B3 is equal to x.

However, what I cant seem to work out is if BOTH A3 AND B3 are equal to x, then the Print_Area should be set to `Sheet1!$E$1:$I$22,Sheet1!$M$1:$Q$22`. However INDIRECT wont accept this, and the Print_Area is cleared.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the case wehre the two cells both have X in them, according to your formula, A3 is checked for X and returns true.  The formula goes to the TRUE result and winds up with INDIRECT("Sheet1!$E$1:$I$22) and stops since the check was satisfied.  If you want a range for the X in two cell case, your first condition check should be AND(A3="x", B3="x"), True result, IF(...your formula...) type deal

Comment: My question is why are you using INDIRECT instead of a straight cell reference?  There may be a good reason I am unaware of, but I currently would not be using INDIRECT.

Comment: I am trying to use the result in a named range, that being the Print_Area named range. The named range doesn't accept string values as far as i can tell, therefore the INDIRECT is used to read the value as a range.